# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import in reactjs app

Tags: javascript, import, webpack, babeljs

I have a react app and Im trying to create a dynamic form using react-jsonschema-form, I have the below index.js file

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

import Form from "react-jsonschema-form";

const schema = {
  title: "Todo",
  type: "object",
  required: ["title"],
  properties: {
    title: {type: "string", title: "Title", default: "A new task"},
    done: {type: "boolean", title: "Done?", default: false}
  }
};


const log = (type) => console.log.bind(console, type);

render((
<Form schema={schema}
    onChange={log("changed")}
    onSubmit={log("submitted")}
    onError={log("errors")} />), document.getElementById("app"));
```

below is the .babelrc file

```
{
  "presets": ["react"]
}
```

and I've the webpack config like below

```
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var HtmlWebpackPluginConfig = new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  template: __dirname + '/app/index.html',
  filename: 'index.html',
  inject: 'body'
})

module.exports = {
entry: [
    './app/index.js'
],
output: {
    path: __dirname + '/dist',
    filename: "index_bundle.js"
},
module: {
    loaders: [
        {
            test: /\.js$/, 
            exclude: /node_modules/, 
            loader: "babel-loader"
        },
        {
            test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)$/,
            loader: 'file?name=assets/[name].[hash].[ext]'
        },
        {
            test: /\.html$/,
            loader: 'html'
        }
    ]
},
plugins: [HtmlWebpackPluginConfig]
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "Sample",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "production": "webpack -p",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server"
   },
  "author": "Sample",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.4.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.30.7",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.2",
    "react-router": "^2.0.0-rc5"
   },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.22.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.10",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.22.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.28.0",
    "html-loader": "^0.4.3",
    "file-loader": "^0.8.5",
    "webpack": "^1.14.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.16.2",
    "axios":"0.15.3",
    "bootstrap":"3.3.7",
    "jquery":"3.1.1"
  }
}
```

once I run the app I'm getting console error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import in reactjs app

Can anyone help to resolve this issue, since I'm new to react, facing difficulties here. Thanks!

Comment: you need to install `babel-preset-es2015` and add it to your `.babelrc` presets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ECMAScript modules aren't something that any browser supports natively yet. I believe Webpack 2 handles them out-of-the-box, but from your config, it seems like you are using Webpack 1, so you need to install [a plugin for that](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-es2015-modules-commonjs/):

```
npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs
```

and extend your `.babelrc`:

```
{
  "presets": ["react"],
  "plugins": ["transform-es2015-modules-commonjs"]
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It's Working fine